# How to set PropertyPath in Silverlight code

Tags: silverlight

In xaml, I have `<Storyboard x:Name="WellGraphicStoryboard"></Storyboard>` in my UserControl.Resources. [I would rather have that in my code, too, but I couldn't figure out how to add the resource.]

In code, then, I have

```
        var duration = new Duration( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 0.2 ) );
        var animation1 = new DoubleAnimation { Duration = duration };
        var sb = WellGraphicStoryboard;
        sb.Duration = duration;
        sb.Children.Clear( );
        sb.Children.Add( animation1 );
        Storyboard.SetTarget( animation1, _wellGraphic );
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty( animation1, new PropertyPath( "SymbolSize" ) );
        animation1.To = 14;
        sb.Begin( );
```

_wellGraphic inherits from MyGraphic, which has a double property called SymbolSize.

When I hit sb.Begin, I get the error, Cannot resolve TargetProperty SymbolSize.

I have also tried 
`Storyboard.SetTarget( animation1, ( MyGraphic )_wellGraphic );`

My objective is to grow the _wellGraphic symbol from its original value (7) to 14, so I'm open to other ways to get this done.

Comment: I guess you get the error on line: Storyboard.SetTargetProperty( animation1, new PropertyPath( "SymbolSize" ) );?

Comment: I get the error on the line:  sb.Begin( );